# show member in a chanel

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

```py
from nextcord.ext import tasks
from nextcord.ext import commands

class online_member(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.bot.loop.create_task(self.online_members())

    @tasks.loop(minutes=10)
    async def online_members(self):
        guild = self.bot.get_guild(1057394146601611334)
        count = 0
        for member in guild.members:
            if not member.bot:
                if member.status != member.status.offline:
                    count =+ 1
        kanal = self.bot.get_channel(1060686055055048798)
        await kanal.edit(name=f"Online Members: {count}")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(online_member(bot))
```

I have no error but it shows 0. It should show 1. Does someone know what to do? I asked many people and they do not know how to solve it.

Comment: Why do you think it should be 1?  Have you printed out the "bot" and "status" values to make sure you're getting what you think you are?

Answer (score 0):

1. In order for your bot to see member's status, you should enable the `member` and `presence` intents :

   ```py
   intents = discord.Intents.default()
   intents.members = True
   intents.presences = True

   bot = commands.Bot(..., intents=intents)
   ```

   Don't forget to enable them in the **[Discord developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)** under bot, then **Privileged Gateway Intents**
2. Also, on line 15, you may want to change your check to something like

   ```py
   member.status != nextcord.Status.offline
   ```

Hope this helps :)